# Should a fast shooting tankette bother with using APFSDS against frontal armor of main battle tank?

Tags: warfare, modern, armoured-vehicles

I'm thinking about something loosely resemble RDF/LT:

[image]

So the whole idea is a vehicle much lighter than a main battle tank, with gun of caliber 75 mm but able to shoot six rounds in very short succession. It's intended to give direct fire support plus it's expected to be able to be cost effective in fighting main battle tanks. It's based on theoretically correct assumption that in tank duels the decisive factor tend to be who managed to score first direct hit. So at least in theory it's supposed to have some chance... except that such gun is not even supposed to be able to penetrate MBT frontal armor and any adversary would be using that mercilessly.

OK, so how to use such vehicle when facing a MBT head on?
Should it try to send 6 APFSDS hoping for miraculously finding weak spot or miraculously hitting the same place twice? Should it use HE to try to make enemy tank combat ineffective by damaging gun / track / optics and later finish of target? Different approach?

APFSDS:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armour-piercing_fin-stabilized_discarding_sabot

Comment: Have you had an opportunity to play World of Tanks? It's actually a good tool for learning the light vs heavy tank conundrum. Usually the bigger tanks can take a hit while they figure out how to put a round through the smaller tank. Nobody wants to shoot a tank face-on unless you're shooting at a line of them coming your way. 

The problem I would have is that you're talking about last century's technology. It's a LOT cheaper to equip a small fire-team with antitank missiles than to field a whole tank.

Comment: You question is well put and I won't downvote it, but you have my VTC. I feel this is a  question for a real world military Q&A website, not worldbuilding.

Comment: @RobertRapplean military planners are supposed to be fighting the _last_ war. Apparently some people haven't noticed the conflicts that have happened recently...

Comment: (unless the OP is genuinely asking about early cold war tech, in which case they'll be forgiven for ignoring the teachings of saint javelin, etc, but they should clarify in their question)

Comment: What does HE mean?

Comment: I don't follow the question. You say "Here is a tank whose gun does not work on other tanks. Should we use the gun anyway or should we use something else?". The obvious answer is to use something else. Something that does work on other tanks. That is a consistent answer with the level of detail in the question. But surely that is not all you are asking for?

Comment: Your lightly armored anti-MBT tanks would get destroyed by lightly armored lightly gunned vehicles supporting the MBT's (think Bradley's) or Jeep/Humvee-type vehicles firing missiles. Someone will always deploy a counter to whatever you have.

Comment: @Daron HE=High Explosive. Essentially a shell that explodes on contact or a fuze delay sending shrapnel or using concussive force to do damage. You MIGHT be able to get away with overpressure against a modern western MBT. You're going to need a lot of HE though. I think OP is asking how to utilize an auto cannon on a light tank against MBTs based on the series of questions towards the end.

Comment: There have been a good many reviews gone unjudged and spam not-so-quickly deleted because of your suggestion regarding World of Tanks. Much obliged ;) @RobertRapplean

Comment: @AngryMuppet, Time's not going to suck itself.... :)

Answer (score 5):

Smaller.  Faster.  Cheaper.  Harder hitting.

**Motorbike with missile**

[image: motorcycle wth antitank missiles]

https://www.rideapart.com/news/597123/dnepr-sidecar-bikes-ukraine-war/

The problem with your tankini is that while cute, the armor gives a false sense of security.  It is putatively for fighting big tanks, but you are not going to withstand a hit from a big tank.  You know that.

Take your concept one step further.  Give up on the armor and trade it for speed, visibility off road maneuverability, fuel economy and badassery.  Here are Ukranians with their war bikes (of Ukranian make!) and rockets.  Also very good for your scenario (which seems like a cold war scenario) these motorbikes are basically 1950s-1960s tech.

I like that these are old, high mileage bikes that were doing other things and that in time of need turned out to be good at war.  Much like some of the Ukranian soldiers I see in videos.

Along the same lines: Even smaller.  Slower.  Much Cheaper.  Very cute.  French.

the French Battle Vespa.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vespa_150_TAP

[image: battle vespa]

Comment: This.  There's no point in bringing inadequate armor to a battle.  It just hinders you for minimal benefit.  That's why modern warships are basically unarmored.

Comment: @LorenPechtel Are you taking in to account that in recent wars most losses tend to come from artillery and "inadequate armor" is the decisive factor in surviving near hit?

Answer (score 4):

**Depends on Caliber and Technology**

The issue with XM274 MCAAC was that it didn't have the desired penetration values against contemporary Soviet MBTs. 75mm, even rapid fire isn't going to cut it, especially in combat settings. In order to get positive effect, you'd need to waste a lot of ammo. The second issue is that 75mm is inadequate for anti-bunker operations as well as more dynamic and flexible operations.

What you're looking for is something like the 105mm M35 gun and MRAAS (Multi Role Armament and Ammunition System). Something like this is capable of firing a wider and better range of warheads with a heavier caliber. Tests showed that MRAAS had comparable penetration to M256. M35 can also be fit onto light tanks. Combined with more advanced weapons systems integration, you can pack a serious punch with modern ammunition. M35 also opens up the avenue for gun launched missiles.

In terms of operation. What you have is essentially a slow firing autocannon. Aiming at optics, barrels and specific weak points using anything other than highly sophisticated and automated targeting systems is more than likely to miss during combat conditions. Furthermore, sending multiple rounds down range, with very specific points on target, leaves you exposed for far too long. At long distance engagement, which is often how tanks fight, hitting a barrel is going to be nearly impossible. Even more so during non-ideal conditions.

Realistically what you'll want to do is have your light tank identify a target. And fire rapid shots down range and scoot away. Multiple APFSDS on the same or areas near initial impact will severely degrade a tanks armor. Even the frontal plate of a Western MBT will start to face significant stress with that many APFSDS rounds hitting it. Enough rounds will eventually cause penetration. Return fire is a tossup. If your initial salvo doesn't outright kill or stun the enemy tank crew, return fire is almost guaranteed to kill your light tank. Even being generous and assuming your 105mm gun is using swing breach, auto loading, recoil dampening, and cased telescoped ammunition; your light tank is exposed in combat action for far longer than a classic MBT. Your light tank needs to expend multiple rounds, your enemy needs only one. This can be mitigated with faster rates of fire and better technology, but the lower limit will always be higher than that of the firing time of an enemy main gun.

Chemical effect rounds, such as HE/High Explosive and HESH/High Explosive Squash Head are not going to be effective against sloped MBT armor. Especially with the advent of ERA and active protection systems. The British are already aware of this as they have met the upper limit of their HESH rounds. A 105mm can allow you to fire gun launched missiles or even rockets if you really need to. MRAAS allowed the 105 to fire a HEAT missile essentially, combined with some taller optics you could manage some top attack capability. You can get away with gun launched HEAT, though ERA panels will prove challenging depending on how advanced they are in your setting.

With lower caliber guns like the 75mm, the best you can get is mission kills against modern MBTs. With larger ones like 105mm, you can achieve penetration by concentration as well as mission kills. Though it's likely that a 105mm tank crew won't be looking for mission kills by targeting optics at extreme ranges.

That said, I strongly advise that you look up the differences in Soviet/Russian and Western MBT armor design and APFSDS. NATO MBTs are larger and shaped in a way to defeat incoming Russian warheads. The Russians/Soviet are shaped in a way to defeat NATO APFSDS and armor. There's a reason that there are some differences between how Russia and NATO construct and build their APFSDS rounds. Each is designed specifically to deal with a specific type of tank design. Depending on what your enemy tank looks like, how its built and as a result what ammunition you are using, the number of rounds you are firing would be different.

Comment: Can you point me to source stating that's 75mm is insufficient against bunkers, while 105mm is sufficient? I haven't seen anything on this subject.

Comment: @Shadow1024 Getting ammo data on XM274 is way harder than getting information than on MRAAS. I can link you a video that has sources in the description, however getting the pdfs is going to be challenging. The video does talk about it, however w/ screenshots. From a general analysis, XM274 was mainly firing high velocity rounds. Post ww2 studies showed the impact of firing HE out of a high velocity gun and the effects (see 76 vs 75mm debate). 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XB30mmmDuT4
If you want information on MRAAS that's much more doable and I should be able to help.

Comment: https://tankandafvnews.com/2015/10/21/from-the-vault-comparison-of-performance-of-75mm-and-76mm-tank-gun-ammo/

Digitized information comparing 75 and 76mm

Answer (score 2):

Your "tankette" doesn't fill the fire support role OR the anti-tank role.

For fire support, you want:

1. 30mm for range, penetration of most IFVs, and ability to deploy a variety of ammunition types, including smart munitions - AP, HE, tracer, HE timed/ranged burst.
2. High cannon elevation for support in mountains and cities.
3. "Trench sweeper" burst functionality - combination of range-finder and programmable munitions to explode over trenches and just inside windows.

For AT, you want either a real 120mm+ cannon or an ATGM.

Your "75mm 6-round burst" achieves precisely nothing - it's overkill for APCs, IFVs, and infantry and insufficient to penetrate a modern MBT from the frontal arc. At most, it would be an impromptu way to attack reinforced concrete hardpoints.

If you are in the modern world or later, what you are looking for is your vehicle with a 30mm ([at most 40mm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bofors_40_mm_L/60_gun)) rapid fire auto-cannon, very, very advanced optics, data integrations, drones, and some sort of hand-waivey "very fast ATGM" with F&F and ability to paint and fire on multiple targets. You also want a hand-wavey multi-channel solution for when the future-enemy-MBT pops thermal smoke with radar chaff to counter Javelin / lased-solutions (TOW, early Hellfire, Konkurs, etc). Potentially, your ATGM not only flies fast but fires multiple missile solutions - one to take the APS hit, another to jam the APS, a couple more for good measure if there is a hard-kill laser/auto-cannon solution.

That way you get a fast shooty-scooty able to take on an MBT while providing fire support for infantry and defending itself against low flying drones and incoming missiles, because you will give it magic mm-wave radar tied to your magic, automated, fast-pivoting, high-elevation, hyper-precise auto-cannon that will be able to air-burst incoming (that's if you don't give it a laser point-defense solution).

Answer (score 0):

Listen to the lessons of St. Javelin!

Even if you're determined to make a baby tank, don't fire at the enemy tank.  Rather, you fire a round **over** the enemy tank that throws a fragment down when it flies over.